# get the range of dictionary values from Array of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In my response JSON i need to parse a range of values from a array of dictionary.
Here is my response,

```
“List”: [
      {
         "event_desc": "On"
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Go”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Start”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": "Off”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Rework”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": "On"
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Start”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": "Off”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Swipe”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": "On"
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Work”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Repair”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": “Off”
      },
      {
         "event_desc": "On"
      }
]
```

here i want to separate the values by range of "On" & "Off" 
that is

```
list1=[ {event_desc:On},{event_desc:Go},{event_desc:Start},{event_desc:Off}]
list2=[{event_desc:On},{event_desc:Start},{event_desc:Off}]
list3= [{event_desc:On},{event_desc:Work},{event_desc:Repair},{event_desc:Off}]
```

Help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: That is a really awkward way to represent the data. It would be better to restructure your JSON to something that better represents the meaning of the information.

Comment: The OP has an array of single-key dictionaries. It's an awkward data structure, but it **is** ordered.

Comment: Yes, I realised that.

Comment: First get all the values in an array. then for(NSString *string in arr){
        if([string isEqualToString:@"On"]){
            //add to array
            while ([string isEqualToString:@"Off"]) {
                 //add to array
            }
            //create new array and repeats 
        }
    }

Comment: Check my answer, It will return your desired arrays in one array!! And yes as @DuncanC said it is awkward structure! you should change it if possible! If you have to keep it as it is then you can manage it like i have mentioned in my answer!

Comment: @DuncanC Thank u. this is not my exact response with single-key dictionaries this is only for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
NSArray *yourArr;   // posted in question
NSMutableArray *resultArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
BOOL flag = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < yourArr.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dic = [yourArr objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[dic objectForKey:@"event_desc"] isEqualToString:@"On"]) {
        flag = YES;
    }
    if (flag) {
        [tempArr addObject:dic];
    }
    if ([[dic objectForKey:@"event_desc"] isEqualToString:@"Off"]) {
        flag = NO;
        [resultArr addObject:[tempArr mutableCopy]];
        [tempArr removeAllObjects];
    }
}
NSLog(@"your result array : %@",resultArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSArray *parsedJson = nil; //Should have your parsed json list array here
    NSMutableArray *eventList = [@[] mutableCopy]; // This will be your final array of list events
    NSMutableArray *eventEntry = [@[] mutableCopy]; // Will contain each list event from event_desc On to event_desc Off

    for (NSDictionary *event in parsedJson) {

        if ([event[@"event_desc"] isEqualToString:@"On"]) {
            [eventEntry removeAllObjects];
            [eventList addObject:eventEntry];

        }else if(([event[@"event_desc"] isEqualToString:@"Off"]) ){
            [eventEntry addObject:event];
            [eventList addObject:eventEntry]; // Add each eventEntry to main array as its complete.

        }else{
            [eventEntry addObject:event];

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Result eventList array : %@",eventList);
```

Comment: eventList gives empty only

Comment: there should be some minor mistake, but the logic should work. Can you please paste the code that you have tried about, along with the JSON. I can get it working in no time.